# Molecular add-on particles won't interact with a non-animated rigid body

Tags: add-on, rigid-body-simulation

I'm trying to make molecular add-on particles to interact with other rigid bodies and it appears that they can interact with an **animated** rigid body, but not with **non-animated** rigid body. Does that make any sense or I'm doing something wrong?

As soon as I'm animating the glass jar and move it with the keyframes, the particles are moving along in it (strangely squeezing into one corner and each other due to the gravity, but then distribute evenly again when it stops, but that's not my current issue), but as soon as I remove the animation and try to tip over that jar with a cube, they stop interacting with the jar and stay in one place, while the jar falls over.

I read people are rather having the other way around issues, does anyone have the expertise to see what's wrong there?

Thank you in advance!

[image]

Comment: I have to login to view your file (what if i can't or don't want to?) You might want to consider using the file sharing site especially for this Blender StackExchange. It's over here: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Hi Fjoersteller, I'm sorry that was unintentional, I thought I've shared the file properly. And thanks for the file sharing service tip, done!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like some cache conflict.

[image]

[image]

Notes:

- The glass jar should be Physics Properties > Rigid Body > **Collision > type Mesh** (not Convex because it should behave like filled object, but it didn't, hmm ...)
- it is always better to **Apply Scale (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>)** to avoid weird behaviour of boundaries
- only make a difference if **Substeps** is changed from 4 to **1**
  (but changing it back to 4, it explodes in some point of anim, because of some previously cached data, that I'm not able clear from file even I change amount of particles, that always helped in crisis like this.

---

### Bake to Keyframes

What I can recommend is to select glass jar and **Bake to Keyframes** (if you played all animation so rigid body was cached, baked avoids caching RB. Since than I don't have an issue with molecules.

Also it solves cube (that is pushing the glass) to affect particles.

[image]

After bake you can use **Decimate** function (with cursor hovering in *Graph Editor*) to simplify *F-curve*.

[image]

Comment: Hi mate, thank you for your suggestions! Though it's getting even more interesting. Not sure why, your bake was working fine as expected. As soon I freed the bake and baked again with the exact settings you made, the particles again stay in their place while the glass bowl tips over.

Comment: vklidu, could you please advise the sequence of bake I should do? I'm baking the rigid world first, then baking the molecular addon. Is that how you baked your version?

Comment: No, I baked only Molecular, by baking RigidBody World became baked Molecular as well but in very weird way.

Comment: Okay... Tried that too. Very strange.

Comment: Sorry mate, what's your Blender version? Mine is the official 2.83.0

Comment: I use the same, and it is exploding in end part of anim again now too, there are visible frames with outdated sim. Even I delete all caches (world rig and particles) it still writes some cache data are stored. Blender has quite a lot of these particle cache headaches. Usually I fix it by changing amount of particles that resets it, but it is not working now. Also Im not sure how precisely was molecular add-on ported to 2.8x version so it can be poor blenders particles in combination with some add-on issue.

Comment: Yeah. That doesn't explain though why I can't bake properly at all... Thanks for spending your time on my problem anyway!

Comment: Oh, forgot to mention, I don't have that explosion that you are experiencing. So different behaviour on the same file.

Comment: One suggestion that probably would work for you, see last part of answer. Note to Explosion - yes it is because your cache state that stacks randomly is different.

Comment: Baking to keyframes did the trick for me! I still have a feeling that's rather a workaround in my case, but it works, which is the most important! Thank you very much

Comment: Yes it is workarround (I feel bad the same), but these cache glitches are for years in blender and no dev is going to try to fix now, because of complexity and fact that new node based particle system is planned. BTW for the purpose you want to achieve I was using Liero's addon https://blenderartists.org/t/copy-particles-to-rigid-bodies/563269

Comment: Thank you, I'll give it a read and try!